# How to to achieve clean correlation table output w/ corstarsl() function?

Tags: r, html-table, formatting

There's a nice correlation table function [around](http://myowelt.blogspot.ch/2008/04/beautiful-correlation-tables-in-r.html) (the only one I know producing this special kind of familiarity to ones eye). *Bertold* already has modified the code in order to achieve a nicer output. However, there are situations e. g. w/ negative correlations when the output still looks somewhat messed up.

In the following I show the function first and below a minimal example:

```
corstarsl <- function(x){
  # corstars1() computes a correlation matrix w/ significance stars
  require(Hmisc)
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  R <- rcorr(x)$r
  p <- rcorr(x)$P

  ## define significance levels
  mystars <- ifelse(p < .001, "***", 
                    ifelse(p < .01, "** ", 
                           ifelse(p < .05, "* ", " ")))

  ## correlation matrix w/ two digits
  R <- format(round(cbind(rep(- 1.11, ncol(x)), R), 2))[, -1]

  ## build a new matrix that includes the correlations w/ appropriate stars
  Rnew <- matrix(paste(R, mystars, sep = ""), ncol = ncol(x))
  diag(Rnew) <- paste(diag(R), " ", sep = "")
  rownames(Rnew) <- colnames(x)
  colnames(Rnew) <- paste(colnames(x), "", sep = "")

  ## remove upper triangle
  Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
  Rnew[upper.tri(Rnew, diag = TRUE)] <- ""
  Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew)

  ## remove last column and return the matrix (which is now a data frame)
  Rnew <- cbind(Rnew[1:length(Rnew) - 1])
  return(Rnew)
}
```

**Example:**

```
library(MASS)
n <- 100
mymeans <- c(10, 12, 15, 17) # means of each var
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, -.45, .16, -.71,
                  -.45, 1, -.71, .09,
                  .16, -.71, 1, -.17,
                  -.71, .09, -.17, 1), ncol = 4)
dat <- mvrnorm(n = n, mu = mymeans, Sigma, empirical = TRUE)

(cortab <- corstarsl(as.data.frame(dat)))
##          V1       V2     V3
## V1                         
## V2 -0.45***                
## V3    0.16  -0.71***       
## V4 -0.71***    0.09  -0.17 

# or with htmlTable():
library(htmlTable)
htmlTable(cortab, 
      align = paste(rep('l', ncol(cortab)), collapse = ''))
```

**Disrupted output:**

***Edit***: With the left-align I'm almost there, but how to give the positive values more space?
[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve a better formatting of the result *inside the function* (decimal points should be aligned)?

Comment: Left-align the elements and force a space before positive correlations?

Comment: @ekstroem Ok, great, with your suggestion I found out how to left-align the values in `htmlTable()`, see edit.. But how to add space to the positive values? Can't I modify the `corstarsl()` output somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tableHTML` and use the `widths` argument to control the widths of columns. Also, you would need to use `&nbsp;` which is the html character for a space like this:

```
#convert to character
cortab[] <- lapply(cortab, as.character)
#if the cell does not start with a minus add an html space
cortab[] <- lapply(cortab, function(x) {

 ifelse(!startsWith(x, '-'), paste0('&nbsp;', x), x)

})

#convert to html with tableHTML
#control the column widths with the widths argument
library(tableHTML)
tableHTML(cortab, widths = c(40, 60, 60, 60), theme = 'scientific') %>%
 add_css_column(list('text-align', 'left !important'), columns = 1:4)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, looks a lot better, though it is still not publishable like this. The `&nbsp;` seems slightly to much. But since the approach is known thank you, maybe the perfect solution will come.

Comment: You are very welcome. HTML characters like `&nbsp;` are standard practice when dealing with html tables. Out of curiosity why wouldn't it be publishable? `tableHTML` gives you the flexibility to make the table exactly as you like. I just used a theme here but you can make the table exactly as you wish, in order to be publishable. have a look at the [tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/tableHTML.html). You can add any kind of CSS you like.

Comment: It is not that `tableHTML` would not be nice or so! As I wrote, the positive values are placed slightly too much right in the table alignment.

Comment: There is a chance the html hyphen code `&#45;` will fix it, if you replace the minus sign with that.