# correlation matrix with p-value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose I want conduct correlation matrix

```
library(dplyr)

data(iris)
iris %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  cor(y =iris$Petal.Width, method = "spearman") %>%  round(2)
```

now we see

```
              [,1]
Sepal.Length  0.83
Sepal.Width  -0.29
Petal.Length  0.94
Petal.Width   1.00
```

i want that statistical significant correlation were marked by *
where

```
*<0,05
**<0,01
*** <0,001
```

ho to do it?

Comment: Did you meant `library(Hmisc);rcorr(as.matrix(iris[1:4]), iris$Petal.Width)$P`

Comment: @D.Joe Please see my update. I believe in my previous post I did not specify `method = "spearman"` in the right place, so I got a different P value. Now I have fixed that.

Answer (score 6):

A solution using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse). We can convert the data frame to long format, create list column using `nest`, and then use `map` to perform `cor.test` for each subset. After that, `map_dbl` can extract the P value by specifying the name `"p.value"`. `dat1` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

data(iris)
dat1 <- iris %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -Petal.Width) %>%
  group_by(Column) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(Cor = map(data, ~cor.test(.x$Value, .x$Petal.Width, method = "spearman"))) %>%
  mutate(Estimate = round(map_dbl(Cor, "estimate"), 2), 
         P_Value = map_dbl(Cor, "p.value"))

dat1
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   Column       data               Cor         Estimate  P_Value
#   <chr>        <list>             <list>         <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 Sepal.Length <tibble [150 x 2]> <S3: htest>    0.83  4.19e-40
# 2 Sepal.Width  <tibble [150 x 2]> <S3: htest>   -0.290 3.34e- 4
# 3 Petal.Length <tibble [150 x 2]> <S3: htest>    0.94  8.16e-70
```

If you don't need the list columns, you can use `select` to remove them.

```
dat1 %>% select(-data, -Cor)
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Column       Estimate  P_Value
#   <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 Sepal.Length    0.83  4.19e-40
# 2 Sepal.Width    -0.290 3.34e- 4
# 3 Petal.Length    0.94  8.16e-70
```

Now we can use `mutate` and `case_when` to add the label to show significance.

```
dat2 <- dat1 %>%
  select(-data, -Cor) %>%
  mutate(Significance = case_when(
    P_Value < 0.001  ~ "*** <0,001",
    P_Value < 0.01   ~ "** <0,01",
    P_Value < 0.05   ~ "*<0,05",
    TRUE             ~ "Not Significant"
  ))
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   Column       Estimate  P_Value Significance
#   <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>       
# 1 Sepal.Length    0.83  4.19e-40 *** <0,001  
# 2 Sepal.Width    -0.290 3.34e- 4 *** <0,001  
# 3 Petal.Length    0.94  8.16e-70 *** <0,001
```

Comment: You could also use `map2` `map2(iris[1:3], iris["Petal.Width"], ~ {Cor <- cor.test(.x, .y, method = "spearman"); tibble(Estimate = Cor$estimate, PValue = Cor$p.value)}) %>% bind_rows(.id = 'Column')`

Comment: @akrun This is a nice solution. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: when i get dat1 , i have the error  dat1 %>% select(-data, -Cor)
Error in select(., -data, -Cor) : unused arguments (-data, -Cor) why it is not work:)

Comment: @D.Joe I don't know. Could you make sure you are using the `select` function from the `dplyr` package?

Answer (score 4):

You could adapt [`corstarsl()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48043464/6574038) to your needs.

```
corFun <- function (x) {
  library(Hmisc)
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  R <- rcorr(x, type="spearman")$r
  p <- rcorr(x, type="spearman")$P
  stars <- ifelse(p < 0.001, "***", ifelse(p < 0.01, "** ", 
                                             ifelse(p < 0.05, "* ", " ")))
  R <- format(round(cbind(rep(-1.11, ncol(x)), R), 2))[, -1]
  Rnew <- matrix(paste(R, stars, sep = ""), ncol = ncol(x))
  diag(Rnew) <- paste(diag(R), " ", sep = "")
  rownames(Rnew) <- colnames(x)
  colnames(Rnew) <- paste(colnames(x), "", sep = "")
  Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
  Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew)
  return(Rnew)
}
```

***Yielding***

```
> data.frame(r=corFun(iris[, -5])[, 4])
                    r
Sepal.Length  0.83***
Sepal.Width  -0.29***
Petal.Length  0.94***
Petal.Width     1.00
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two `tidyverse` options that both make use of `tidy` from `broom`. Using `tidy` will pull out the estimates and p-values, so you don't have to do that manually. I made a vector of breaks for the different significance levels you want to show, so you can use `cut` to cut and label the p-values easily; keeping this in a named vector also makes it more repeatable.

The first time I used `cor.test`, which pipes into the `tidy.htest` method. The second time I used `rcorr` from `Hmisc`, which pipes into the `tidy.rcorr` method.

In the first case, I `gather`ed the data frame into a long format to compare each measure against `Petal.Width`; in the second case, which required a matrix, I used the full dataset and then filtered for either column containing `Petal.Width`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

sig_breaks <- c(zero = 0, "***" = 0.001, "**" = 0.01, "*" = 0.05, NS = Inf)

iris %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  gather(key = measure, value = value, -Petal.Width) %>%
  group_by(measure) %>%
  do(mtx = cor.test(.$value, .$Petal.Width, method = "spearman")) %>%
  broom::tidy(mtx) %>%
  mutate(stars = cut(p.value, breaks = sig_breaks, include.lowest = T, labels = names(sig_breaks)[2:5]))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#> # Groups:   measure [3]
#>   measure      estimate statistic  p.value method        alternative stars
#>   <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>         <fct>       <fct>
#> 1 Petal.Length    0.938    35061. 8.16e-70 Spearman's r… two.sided   ***  
#> 2 Sepal.Length    0.834    93208. 4.19e-40 Spearman's r… two.sided   ***  
#> 3 Sepal.Width    -0.289   725048. 3.34e- 4 Spearman's r… two.sided   ***

iris %>%
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  Hmisc::rcorr(type = "spearman") %>%
  broom::tidy() %>%
  filter(column1 == "Petal.Width" | column2 == "Petal.Width") %>%
  mutate(stars = cut(p.value, breaks = sig_breaks, include.lowest = T, labels = names(sig_breaks)[2:5]))
#>        column1     column2   estimate   n      p.value stars
#> 1 Sepal.Length Petal.Width  0.8342888 150 0.0000000000   ***
#> 2  Sepal.Width Petal.Width -0.2890317 150 0.0003342981   ***
#> 3 Petal.Length Petal.Width  0.9376668 150 0.0000000000   ***
```

Created on 2018-05-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).